# What is the most efficient way to create and mine obsidian after bug patch?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Now that the "Infiniobsidian" obsidian generator method has been patched as of the more recent snapshots, what is the most efficient way to generate and mine obsidian?

Comment: There was a method to generate obsidian other than just finding huge pools of lava beneath the surface?

Comment: @Rapitor No, this is asking how to do it since of the **latest snapshot**. Many old methods have been removed.

Comment: the old method was with a cobble generator and redstone but that has now been fixed.

Comment: What changed in the latest snapshot? Does water no longer turn lava into obsidian?

Comment: @Rapitor Many old methods don't work due to changes in the snapshots.

Comment: @Rapitor Water still turns lava to obsidian but that obviously requires a lot of lava.

Comment: Basically i need 6 stacks of obsidian for what im working on or more, so i want this a lot

Comment: @Flaunting are you using vanilla or is BuildCraft an option?

Comment: Purely Vanilla minecraft

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms The only change to obsidian in the 1.8 update is the fix of bug [MC-4329](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-4239), otherwise known as the [Infiniobsidian bug](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Obsidian_farming#Infiniobsidian_bug). It allowed you to turn restone and certain other materials into obsidian.

Comment: @Caleb Maybe that's what the OP is talking about?

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms Just clarifying.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question why is it closed

Comment: and the question i am supposedly duplicating is about saftey

Comment: Some folks do not read the full question text, or assume that closevote #1 knew what they were doing and vote en masse.  I have voted to reopen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have access to it, the End is a great place to find a lot of obsidian; there are large solid pillars of it, which should mean uninterrupted mining. Otherwise, I'd just recommend flooding underground lava pools and mining it out layer by layer. So long as you aren't completely submerged the mining time isn't increased by standing in water, so you can keep some at your feet to turn lava into obsidian as it is uncovered and prevent drops falling in.

The fastest way to mine it is an Efficiency V Diamond Pickaxe, with a Haste II Beacon set up nearby. This will reduce the time taken to mine each piece from 9.4 seconds to 1.8 seconds, or 32 blocks a minute.

If you really need a lot of obsidian, and are willing to get involved, you may want to look into a wither obsidian farm. This uses the fact that the End spawn platform regenerates when an entity enters the End, and that the wither will destroy any blocks directly on top of it. The basis is that you trap a wither in the spot where the platform spawns, then send items through with a dropper. Here is a video of it:

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient (and renewable) source of obsidian is through the use of what I have called "End Platform Farming".

You need three things:

1. Access to [The End](https://minecraft.wiki/w/The_End)
2. [A Diamond Pickaxe](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Diamond_Pickaxe)
3. Two [Ender Chests](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ender_Chest)

Sleep next to the End Portal to set your spawn and place the first Ender Chest next to your bed (or anywhere in the area).

Now you need to travel to The End with your Diamond Pickaxe and your remaining Ender Chest, you will spawn on a 5x5 obsidian platfform that looks like this:

[image: Obsidian Platform]

Place the other Ender Chest somewhere you can find it in the end (do not place it on the obsidian).

Mine out all the obsidian with your Diamond pickaxe and place everything into the chest (including the pickaxe). Now kill yourself somehow so you respawn in the overworld.

When you respawn all of the obsidian and your pickaxe will be in the Ender Chest in the overworld.

Grab your pickaxe out of the chest and repeat the process. Every time you go back through the End Portal the obsidian platform will regenerate.

Remember this method is renewable, meaning it will never run out of obsidian.

Comment: the only downside to this is if you spawn over the void then there is nothing under the obsidian

Comment: This is true, but if you build a bridge to the main section then build back a little lower, you can build your own platform under the obsidian, making it so you can mine and pick up the obsidian safely.

Answer (score 1):

Maketh a trip to yonder Nether, good chum!  (this assumes you have enough obsidian to go there first, which for 10 blocks isn't that much to just find underground).

Gather ye an inventory full of empty buckets, bring thy buckets to the Nether, then fill thy buckets with the near-infinite lava supply the Nether has to offer.

Once ye have retrieved thy lava, bringeth thy lava near yonder ocean with yon empty bucket.  Thou should'st be able to make obsidian aplenty.

((In short: Go get some lava from the Nether.  It's boundlessly rich in it.))

Comment: I'm not really asking how to get a lot of it. I want to know what the quickest method is now. the old generator method was great as you didn't need to keep moving dimensions. I have an idea that i haven't heard anyone doing but i need to test it

Comment: @Flaunting Sorry, but this is the extent of my expertise in Obsidian-gathering. If you have an idea though, I encourage you to try it. If it works, you can even answer your own question (which is encouraged: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer )

Comment: Actually, you only need 10 blocks of obsidian, the corners aren't necessary.

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms Ironically, I miscounted not because of corners, but because I thought it had to be 3 blocks wide at the top. Which would only be twelve anyway.  Fixing.

Comment: @Zibbobz Well, as of 1.7.2 portals can be any width an height from 5x3 to 20x20.

Answer (score 0):

Efficiency 5 Gold Pickaxe with Haste 2 Beacon.

Diamond tools are not as fast as gold, which is why the Haste icon within the Beacon GUI is that of a gold pick.

Comment: Hi Jason I would like to point out that you can’t mine obsidian with gold tools